# Mostrar una lista al cargar index.html con Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estoy usando SpringBoot y Thymeleaf.

Como puedo hacer para que en index.html se muestren todos los productos al cargar la pagina.

Actualmente products.html muestra todos los productos de la bd y en index.html se ve el fragment con  el header del form de products.html pero no se como hacer que se muestren los productos.

Si mi enfoque es incorrecto,de que manera deberia hacerlo?Gracias

index.html

```
<body>
<section layout:fragment="custom-content">
    <br> <br>
    <div class="container">
        <section th:replace="products :: content"></section>
                <br> <br>
        <h2>This is index.html</h2>
        </div>
```

este es index.html con el fragment de products.html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

products.html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div th:fragment="content">

        <h3>This is the fragment from products.html</h3>

        <h2>List of products</h2>
        <table class="table table-stripped">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Image Url</th>
                <th>List</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>

            <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
                <td th:text="${product.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.imageUrl}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/products/numArt/' + product.numArt}">View</a></td>
                <td><a>Edit</a></td>
                <td><a>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button>New Product</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

este es products.html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

controlador

```
@GetMapping("/products")
public String listProducts(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Get all products...");
    model.addAttribute("products", productRepository.findAll());
     return "products";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No se muestran porque el fragmento utiliza el atributo `${products}`. Para que se muestren los productos en index.html debes agregar al controlador IndexController algo similar a listProducts:

```
 model.addAttribute("products", productRepository.findAll());
 return "index";
```

Tienes que declarar el repositorio.